# any plugin or tool to auto fill the Args for the POJOs in intellij?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, pojo

every time while writing the test cases i need to write all the object constructors and setters manually for ex:

Pojo.java

```java
    public class Pojo {
        private int a;
        private int b;
        private int c;
        // getters and setters
        // equals and hashCode
        // toString
    }
```

PojoTest.java

```java
//@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class PojoTest {
    @Autowired
    private Pojo p;

    @Test
    public void getValues() {
    p.setA(1);
    p.setB(2);
    assertEquals(p.getA(),1);
    }
    }
```

here if you look at this below code manually writing the setters

```
     p.setA(1);
        p.setB(2);
```

is there any plugin to auto fill the Args based on data types in intelliJ?

Comment: Your test example doesn't make much sense. You wouldn't inject a simple POJO and you wouldn't assert the result of getter/setter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use instancio library for automating data setup in unit tests.

Instancio uses reflection to populate objects, including nested objects and collections. A single method call provides you with a fully populated instance of a class, ready to be used as an input to your test case

MVN Dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.instancio</groupId>
    <artifactId>instancio-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Example:

```java
Pojo student = Instancio.create(Pojo.class);
```

Reference:
https://www.instancio.org/

Comment: i know lombok and getters , setters generator, 
my question was stubbing these setters in test cases.
manually adding values using setters or args constructor.

is there any plugin or tool to generate those stubbed setters or args constructor

Comment: i have seen this either in one of the articles but for this we need to add additional dependency , i was more looking for IDE plugin